# Why was my comment removed?

Tags: discussion

I posted a comment to [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/647/1050). It was about the irrelevance of giving numbers in 18 significant digits, especially if one of the factors for the calculation only has 4 significant digits. I thought this comment was to the point, especially if the site wants to be professional, and IIRC it also had a couple of votes. I just wonder why it was removed (together with a reply to it).

Answer (score 6):

It was requested that the comment thread be removed because it was degenerating into argument without any action being taken, or needing to be taken. If you feel the significant digit issue still needs to be dealt with, you can suggest an edit to the answer or post your own.